# What is the difference between "domain" and "field"?

Tags: synonyms

I have those two sentences and I have to choose where to put "domain" and where to put "field".

I think that those two words are interchangeable, what is your opinion?

1. John is considered an expert in his ______.
2. I am not able to answer financial questions about the product - that's the ______ of our financial team.

Comment: Where are those sentences from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're right in assuming they *can* both be used in either sentence, but one fits better than the other.

'*To be an expert in someone's field*' is a fixed expression:

The '*expert*' entry [here](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/expert) reads:

> a person who has special skill or knowledge in some particular field; specialist; authority:

'*Field*', in this context, can be [defined](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/field) as:

> - an area of human activity: *the field of human knowledge*
> - a sphere or division of knowledge, interest, etc: *his field is physics*

[Or](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/field):

> A domain of study, knowledge or practice.
> *He was an expert in the field of Chinese history.*

Whereas '*domain*' is defined as:

> - the territory governed by a single ruler or government; realm.
> - a realm or range of personal knowledge, responsibility, etc.

The distinction being that '*field*' is an objective, delimited area of knowledge, and '*domain*' an area over which someone has influence, which is more fitting for the second sentence you provided.